# iTunes Keeps Crashing After Activating iTunes Match

Tags: itunes, itunes-match

This morning I activated iTunes Match.  There were over 20,000 songs to scan and upload, so I walked away and came back to it this afternoon.  Upon returning, I found that iTunes had crashed.  Now any time I try to open iTunes, the window displays but within a second (seemingly as soon as it tries to access iTunes Match, but I have no way of confirming that) it crashes.  So I effectively can't get iTunes to run.

Has this happened for anybody else?  Does anybody have any suggestions for fixing or even diagnosing this?

Comment: Which OS?  Have you tried to repair or reinstall iTunes?

Comment: @techie007: OSX 10.7.3, latest iTunes.  I can try a re-install of iTunes to see if that helps.  Is there a specific way to "repair"?

Comment: I wonder if it's a specific song that's crashing it somehow (since it's scanning/uploading).  If there's a way to identify it, I can remove it and see if that has an effect.

Comment: Re-installing didn't have any effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out there was one or two files which were corrupted somehow.  It had never been a problem before, and they've always played fine.  But for some reason they messed up iTunes Match.

The way I diagnosed it was to revert to a backed up library and export a playlist of everything to a file.  Then I created a new empty library and imported the playlist.  As it scanned, it always crashed around the same time.  I'd go back to a blank new library, manually remove an estimated number of lines from the exported file, and import again.  It took a couple of iterations, but I narrowed it down to a single album.

Once I got rid of the album entirely, everything worked like a charm.